# Apache2 timeout

Tags: php, apache2, timeout

For several weeks now, I've been experiencing timeout problems with Apache2 making my application inacessible. It's an e-commerce website developed in PHP (stack : PHP7.2-FPM, PostgreSQL, Apache2.4.25, Debian 9).
When the site does not respond, it takes a good twenty seconds before displaying the timeout on the browser side. The service status are all good: apache2, database and I have no logs that could help me.

The only leads I have :

- Apache2/PHP configuration, I increased the timeout value bit it didnt't change anything

  ```
  <Proxy "unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm-app.sock|fcgi://localhost">
      ProxySet timeout=1200
  </Proxy>
  ```
- Apache2 version. I have the same problem on another site (basic wordpress) with exactly the same behavior (timeout without specific logs behind, all services UP etc). And Apache2 version of this website is Apache2.4.25

I have a lot of other sites with the same Apache2 configuration, on more recent versions and no problem.

Does this speak to anyone ? Any ideas or anything ? :)

Comment: Check the PHP slow log.

Comment: Hello, this is already in place. And there is no link between slow logs and apache. When the timeout occurs, I have nothing in the slow logs. Which makes me think that the apache layer is the problem

Comment: What is the entry for the "listen" variable in the www.conf file for PHP-FPM. Is it listening on socket or a port?

Comment: Hello, PHP-FPM pool listen on an UNIX socket.